# How to make GWT work with CORS and cookies

Tags: gwt, cookies, csrf, cors

I separated GWT - static code is on CDN and dynamic is on a different server.
I configured this CORS filter on Tomcat7 and it works fine:

http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter-installation.html

However I'm still struggling with getting Cookies to work with GWT and CORS.

I mainly need it for XSRF protection (and few other things):

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideSecurityRpcXsrf

It looks like I have to set withcredentials=true in XMLHttpRequest.

Does anyone know how to do it in GWT?

Answer (score 0):

By default Cookies are not sent with CORS. If you want them, you have to set the `withCredentials` attribute to the low-level `XMLHttpRequest` used by GWT. Unfortunately there is no way to set it from your java code.

A simple hack is that you maintain your own version of `XMLHttpRequest.java` in your source tree (use the same namespace), and modify the `create()` method in this way:

```
private static native XMLHttpRequest create(String responseType) /*-{
  [...]
  xhr.withCredentials = true;
  return xhr;
}-*/;
```

Note: from server side you have to sent this header as well:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

Otherwise, the normal way to deal with authentication in GWT is that you use special headers with the auth info and read it in the server side.

```
builder.setHeader("X-My-Authenticated-Header", "whatever");
```

EDIT: as t.broyer points in his comment below, a `RequestBuilder.setIncludeCredentials` method is in 2.5.1-rc1. So if you are using this release, call this method in when creating your builder.

Comment: Actually, `setWithCredentials` has been added in GWT 2.5.1-rc1: https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/xhr/client/XMLHttpRequest.java?r=11514#368

Comment: Thanks Thomas, its nice to know that the feature is already in gwt.